# DIV above another DIV automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I need a script that will add a div above another div when the page loads, and I need to be able to edit the DIV's html coding directly inside the Javascript code (for a userscript). Currently, I have it replacing a div, and it's kind of a mess.

```
if (document.getElementById ('category_45'))
{
    var wdiv = document.getElementById ('category_45');
    wdiv.innerHTML = '<div id=shoutboxfix><iframe id=reloader name=reloader scrolling=yes frameborder=0 width=1000px height=350px src=http://forums.digitalwarfare247.com/index.php?/shoutbox/index.php#category_shoutbox>';
    wdiv.innerHTML += '<input type="button" value="Refresh ^" onclick="parent.top.reloader.location.reload(true);" /></div>';
    wdiv.innerHTML += '<br />';
}
```

The div I need the new div above's ID is 'category_45', and the HTML coding is `<iframe id=reloader name=reloader scrolling=yes frameborder=0 width=1000px height=350px src=http://forums.digitalwarfare247.com/index.php?/shoutbox/index.php#category_shoutbox>`

Thanks to anyone that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered JQuery? http://api.jquery.com/before/

Comment: the OP didn't tag jQuery to his question. assume he DOESN'T use it

Comment: you cannot assume that the OP *CAN* use a toolkit. if the OP *HAD* that option, he could have tagged it in the first place. not everyone can use a toolkit, not because he don't want to, but maybe he just can't.

Comment: I have never really touched Javascript or jQuery at all, I'm an extreme amateur.  And I can't figure out how to put HTML coding straight into the file.  This is a .js file.

Comment: If you consider yourself an amateur, then I highly recommend you check out a javascript framework like JQuery.  In case you're not aware, every browser has it's own flavoring of javascript syntax. What may work fine with one browser may not work at all with other browser.  A framework like Jquery, (which a .js file itself) allows you to manipulate the DOM without regard to which browser you are using.  What are you refering to with: "...put HTML coding straight into the file."?  It would help me to know how you are embedding your .js file into a webpage. Can you give a little code sample?

Comment: By using the addon Greasemonkey for Firefox.  It lets users make javascript files that load on specified pages, mine being the index of a website's forum.  I want to get their shoutbox page on the index of their site.

Comment: Okay, this link will help you to embed JQuery into your script. http://wiki.greasespot.net/Third-Party_Libraries#jQuery.  Remember, JQuery will help make coding simpler for you. Once you get it working, check out: http://api.jquery.com/before/  If this works, please mark this thread as your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps Mootools ?

```
myThirdElement.inject(mySecondElement, 'before');
```

source: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:inject

Comment: the OP didn't tag MooTools to his question. assume he DOESN'T use it